# Bottle returning responses very slowly

Tags: python, web, bottle

I have created 2 different ways of returning from one of my route-decorated functions:

Method 1:

```
return HTTPResponse(status=200, body=myBody)
```

Method 2 (This is done in order to for after_request hook to read the same response object, for now.):

```
response = bottle.response.copy()
response.status = 200
response.body = myBody
return response
```

myBody is a string, NOT a dict (our upstream library already converts the dict into a string via json.dumps()), and myBody is also large: it is a dictionary with 1 key, but a 600+ member list as the value.

My problem is:
Method 1 returns very fast to the calling client (client is using requests library via a POST request).

Method 2 is about 10 times slower (the calling client waits about 2 mins to get the response, versus 2 seconds in method 1).

I've also disabled any `after_hook` logic just to isolate any other effects.

Any hint as to what might be the root cause?

Comment: Why are you copying the response instead of acting on it?

Comment: @eatmeimadanish either way, the slowness is there.

Comment: Just curious: how many bytes is a typical `myBody`?

Comment: @ronrothmanℝℝ it's 2.4 Megabytes.

Comment: Okay, yeah, that's big enough that I'd expect to see a difference in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient (fastest) way to return your large string is to simply return an iterable. E.g.,

```
return [myBody]
```

In particular: (1) don't copy the response object, and (2) 200 is the default response code, so no need to specify it.

---

Q: Why do I return a list (containing a single string) instead of just the string?

A: We could `return myBody`, but `return [myBody]` is preferred. [Here's why](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content):

> Applications must return an iterable yielding byte strings. You may return a string (because strings are iterable) but this causes most servers to transmit your content char by char.

Comment: Thanks. Aside from not copying the response object, you think not transmitting it as a list is causing the slowness?

But why does transmitting it as HTTPResponse by passing it myBody (also not as a list) does not lead to slowness ?

Comment: Yeah, my guess would be that copying the response is hurting performance more. But just a guess - luckily it's easy enough to test out. Let us know what happens, I'm curious to see

Comment: Returning [myBody] is now much faster! .copy() wasn't slowing down much.
But, why is it not slow when I send in myBody to HTTPresponse and returning HTTPResponse? Shouldn't I send in [myBody] as well ?

Comment: No, it's a different code path when you create a new response object. I'm guessing your strings are VERY large!